# How to count tablets successfully?

Tags: opencv, image-processing

My last question on image recognition seemed to be too broad, so I would like to ask a more concrete question.

First the background. I have already developed a (round) pill counter. It uses something similar to [this tutorial](https://docs.opencv.org/3.2.0/d3/db4/tutorial_py_watershed.html). After I made it I also found something similar with [this other tutorial](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/11/02/watershed-opencv/).

However my method fails for something like this image

[image: The original problem]

Although the segmentation process is a bit complicated (because of the semi-transparency of the tablets) I have managed to get it

[image: segmented image]

My problem is here. How can I count the elongated tablets, separating each one from the image, similar to the final results in the linked tutorials?

So far I have applied distance transform and then my own version of watershed and I got

[image: bad results]

As you can see it fails in the adjacent tablets (distance transform usually does).

Take into account that the solution does have to work for this image and also for other arrangements of the tablets, the most difficult being for example

[image: difficult case]

I am open to use OpenCV or if necessary implement on my own algorithms. So far I have tried both (used OpenCV functions and also programmed my own libraries) I am also open to use C++, or python or other. (I programmed them in C++ and I have done it on C# too).

Comment: It can be easily done with `cv::distanceTransform()`

Comment: @BahramdunAdil Could you provide an example? Asi I wrote I already tried distance transform and watershedoing with the results above. It fails. (Mainly when the tablets are next to each other)

Comment: Didn't you ask that exact same question last week?

Comment: @TA It was argued my question was too general (well it involved pills and tablets of different sizes and characteristics) so I reduced the question to the first of my problems (in a much more concrete way) (and specifying that it should work for more than the same case)

Comment: Have you tried eroding after using the distance transformation?

Comment: @TA After I do the distance transformation I usually apply a Gaussian Filter to smooth it, otherwise watershed breaks the tablets

Answer (score 1):

I am also working on this pill counting problem (I'm much earlier in this process than you are), and to solve the piece you are working on - of touching pills, my general idea how to solve this is to capture contours of the pills once you have a good mask of the pills, and then calculate the area of a single pill.

For this approach I'm assuming that I have enough pills in the image such that the amount of them that are untouching is greater than those which are touching, and no pills overlap one another. For my application, placing this restriction I think is reasonable (humans can do a quick look at the pills they've dumped out, and at least roughly make them not touching without too much work. It's also possible that I could design a tray with some sort of dimples in it such that it would coerce the pills to not be touching)

I do this by sorting the contour areas (which, with the right thresholding should lead to only pills and pill-groups being in the identified contours), and taking the median value.

Then, with a good value for the area of a pill, you can look for contours with areas that are a multiple of that median area (+/- some % error value).
I also use that median value to filter out contours that are clearly not big enough to be pills, and ones that are far too large to be a pill (the latter though could be more troublesome, since it could still be a grouping of touching pills).

Answer (score 0):

Given that the pills are all identical and don’t overlap, simply divide the total pill area by the area of a single pill.

The area is estimated simply counting the number of “pill” pixels.

You do need to calibrate the method by giving it the area of a single pill. This can be trivially obtained by giving the correct solution to one of the images (manual counting), then all the other images can be counted automatically.

Comment: Ideally I would like to have them marked as in https://www.pyimagesearch.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/watershed_output_coins_02.jpg (the pic is for round coins, but similar for tablets)

Comment: @KansaiRobot: Sure, you can try doing it the hard way if you want. Good luck with that!

Comment: Unfortunatelly it is a requirement.